# Unable to Import CucumberOptions and Cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I started learning cucumber. When I created my runner class, I am not able to import  Cucumber and CucumberOptions. Can anyone guide me where I am wrong?

Below are the JAR files i have added :

[image]

My Runner Class :

[image]

Comment: Is your code inline with the version you are using ? I'm using Cucumber 4.7 and your second and third imports are indicated as deprecated in my setup.

Comment: Could you show us your pom.xml or build.gradle?

Comment: when i replaced them with import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions, the error was resolved.. Unfortunately I am getting a new error when i run the class a JUnit test :  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/plugin/event/EventPublisher

Comment: rasklaad - I am manually adding the jars. not using maven or gradle(i dont know them much)

Answer (score 1):

> I am manually adding the jars. not using maven or gradle(i dont know them much)

If you follow the [10 minute tutorial](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) you'll get an introduction that uses Maven dependency management.

In addition to this tutorial I would strongly urge you to invest time in learning either Maven or Gradle along with Cucumber. Amongst other things these tools will automate your dependency management and this can make your life much easier.

For example:

If you want to use Cucumber with JUnit 4 and annotation based step definitions you would declare this minimal set of dependencies in a Maven `pom.xml` file.

```
    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>5.2.0</cucumber.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

By telling Maven what your dependencies are Maven can calculate your transitive dependencies i.e: the dependencies of your dependencies.

This has many advantages. One example would be using the `mvn dependency:tree` command to list all dependencies. This is much faster and much less error prone then downloading jar files by hand and hoping that you have the right ones.

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton >-------------------
[INFO] Building Cucumber-Java Skeleton 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin-vintage:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:2.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:8.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-plugin:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.cucumber:docstring:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.781 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-10T23:00:14+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```